# IOS Simulator or Run device visual studio 2015 apache cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Hello searched various sources on how to run my application on an iOS simulator or run the application on an iOS device by visual studio , but from what I understand I need to have a Mac.

main source:
[VISUAL DOCS](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that's correct. To build for iOS devices from Visual Studio, you do need to setup a Mac build server. You can either follow the instructions on the [page that you linked to](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/), or take a look at the steps on the same site to [use a Cloud-hosted service, MacInCloud](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build_ios_cloud/)